# Import expect script into existing expect script

Tags: expect

Is it possible to import common expect functions into another expect script?

The use case is I have a server accessed via serial console port, so there is a long list of steps to connect and access the serial console.  There are several expect scripts that all need this initial setup and login.  Ie a sample script (ignoring the serial connect steps) might be:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]


spawn ssh $user@$host

set timeout 5

# Login to host
expect {
  "assword:" {
    send -- "$pass\r"
  }
}

expect {
// DO OTHER EXPECT STUFF
}
```

Is it possible to put the login into a common file that is imported/included in every script to setup the initial shell connection and login?

login.exp:

```
# Login to host
expect {
  "assword:" {
    send -- "$pass\r"
  }
}
```

foo.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]


spawn ssh $user@$host

set timeout 5

####include login.exp

expect {
// DO OTHER EXPECT STUFF
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, use the Tcl `source` command: `source login.exp`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  thank you!